# Where vs Find in Rails Api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, ruby-on-rails-5

Let's say I have a student Rails API which having an endpoint that looks like `http://www.example.com/students/1`

What is the preferred way to implement?

```
review = Review.find(inputs[:review_id])
To handle exceptions,
rescue_from Exception, :with => :internal_error
def internal_error(e)
 render json: {error: {message: "Internal Error"} }, :status => 500
end
```

OR

```
review = Review.where(inputs[:review_id]).first
if review.nil?
 render json: {error: {message: "Internal Error"} }, :status => 500
end
```

My question is which is better way for handling non-existent id through the url.

Comment: Well `find` is preferred over `where().first`

Answer (score 3):

You should go with the first approach

```
# reviews_controller.rb
review = Review.find(inputs[:review_id])
```

And

```
# application_controller.rb

# rescue_from Exception, :with => :internal_error

# OR Prefer ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :internal_error # Prefer this one

def internal_error(e)
  render json: {error: {message: "Internal Error"} }, :status => 500
end
```

To make it generic, Add it to `application_controller.rb`

**NOTE:**

- This way you don't have to rescue it in every controller (the second approach you have to)

Comment: It's usuallyh a bad idea to rescue from the generic `Exception`. This way you will either catch `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` and things like `NoMethodError`

Comment: Yes, that's why I have added a comment to prefer `RecordNotFound`

Answer (score 2):

You can add a global `rescue_from` in your base controller (`ApplicationController` for example) and then use the `find` method (Best way to retrieve only one record) :

```
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do |e|
    render status: :not_found, json: { error: { message: e.message } }
  end
```

Every time you try to retrieve a record, if he doesn't exist you will render an error message and a 404 status which stand for a non-existent resource.

Answer (score 0):

Neither. You can just do something like:

```
unless review = Review.find_by(id: inputs[:review_id])
  render json: {error: {message: "record not found"} }, status: :not_found
end
```

Benefits:

1. Does't require endless `nil` checking as mentioned in comments.
2. Avoids unnecessary exception handling.
3. Returns a more informative error message.

Comment: It might break somewhere in the next method or views, or you will have to check for it every where if its present or not

Comment: @DeepakMahakale,  completely agree. if we use `where().first` , everywhere we have to put nil checking , instead of that better through error from beginning if the resource not found.

Answer (score 0):

You should use rescue for manage error

```
def action_name
  review = Review.find(inputs[:review_id])
  render json: review, status: :ok
  rescue # for ever not found
  render json: {}, status: :not_found,nothing: true
end
```

[doc for status list](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render)

and you can use rescue_from on header but this works for every action

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound,with: action_name
```